# Why is Selenium unable to click a button from a list of buttons?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to access a specific button on a webpage so that I can click it and webscrape what's on the other side. I'm trying to use Selenium to return a list of buttons under a specific div so that I can click the first one. However, I receive an error upon clicking the 0th index.

I receive the following error:

> ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
> (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)

Am I unable to click elements if they are in a list? Or could this be something else?

Webpage: https://profiles.ucr.edu/app/home

Picture of HTML and desired ID element. I want to click the red "Browse" button:
[div and button HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cQQ1.png)

Here is the code that I am using, but it returns an error. I commented out the ability to print out the list of buttons:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys    
import time


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"    #path to webdriver executable
wd = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

urlDepartments = 'https://profiles.ucr.edu/app/home'

wd.get(urlDepartments)
time.sleep(1)

idFirst = 'cdk-accordion-child-'
idNum = 0
idNumStr = str(0)
div = wd.find_element_by_id(idFirst + idNumStr)
button = div.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
button[0].click()
#print(button)
```

Comment: What are the steps involved to find the red colored Browse button to be visible on the webpage https://profiles.ucr.edu/app/home?

Comment: Not enough info provided. Usually this occurs when the element is hidden, disabled or covered by an overlay. It's useful to try a wait (element_to_be_clickable ) and that may resolve the error. More info: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotInteractableException.html

Comment: I used "wd.find_element_by_id('cdk-accordion-child-0') to find the div that contains four buttons, where the first is the one that I want. I then used div.find_elements_by_tag_name('button') to find the children button of that div tag

Comment: I will try the wait functionality

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the button to become clickable or maybe it is not shown on the screen yet, you can try something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys    
import time


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"    #path to webdriver executable
wd = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

urlDepartments = 'https://profiles.ucr.edu/app/home'

wd.get(urlDepartments)
time.sleep(1)

idFirst = 'cdk-accordion-child-'
idNum = 0
idNumStr = str(0)
div = wd.find_element_by_id(idFirst + idNumStr)
button = div.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
print("Is visible: " + str(element_name.is_displayed()))
time.sleep(3)
button[0].click()
#print(button)
```

Comment: So, even though Selenium can detect the button, it cannot click it because it cannot "see it"? Similarly to how a human can assume that a login button for StackOverflow exists before they are able to click it since their page hasn't fully loaded yet?

Comment: Also, I plugged in my variable div into element_name, but I got the same error. Was plugging in this variable there the intended idea?